# POSTing a file using cURL doesn't actually post the file

Tags: php, curl

I'm using PHP to post a few files to another PHP application. I need to send multiple files in a request. I am putting

```
["happyfacepng"]=> string(36) "@/var/www/html/imgtest/happyface.png"
```

Into the post array (as well as some other files in the same directory with different key names) and posting them using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$node."/rendernodeinterface.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //Post this to the node
curl_close($ch);
```

And the server on the other end has a blank `$_FILES` , but the post array has

```
["happyfacepng"]=> string(36) "@/var/www/html/imgtest/happyface.png"
```

in it as well as the other non-file data and whatnot. So the sender isn't sending the files along with post. What am I missing here that's preventing cURL from actually posting the contents of these files?

Thank you for helping, I feel like there's a really simple answer to this question that I just can't figure out.

Comment: could this be a permissions issue? Does you PHP script have permission to access that file?

Comment: You should rather use `CURLFile` instead of prefixing `@`.

Comment: I hope I have permissions because I'm running this from the command line as root. I'll look into CurlFile. How would I do multiple files with that?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file1' => $curlfile1, 'file2' => $curlfile2, 'file3' => $curlfile3));` you can make as many curlfile instances as you want.